# How can I hide ‘code behind’ files in asp.net? i.e. files with .cs extension

Tags: asp.net

And creates dlls for all code behind files.

Comment: Which project template are you using? And which version of .NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert your 'Web Site' project to a 'Web Application Project'.

You will be able to pre-compile the site (Publish the site in Visual Studio verbage) which will leave no code-behind files...only compiled dlls.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to deploy the .cs files. If you use the Publish command (Build -> Publish) you will get a folder with the files that need to go to the web server.

Answer (score 1):

Publish your asp.net application instead of copying all files.

You can access publish menu with **ALT + B + H**  shortcut or under Build menu you can find Publish Wb Site menu item.

Answer (score 1):

When you publish your website there is a dll out there check the published folder, It will be soemething like app_code.dll or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend considering [Web Deployment Projects](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/01/25/announcing-rtw-of-visual-studio-2008-web-deployment-projects-wdp.aspx). In addition to giving you pre-compiled output, you get a host of configuration and deployment options, as well as control over how your final output assembly is named.